# Making a button click and process using javascript with Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, click

I'm having two buttons and one button is hidden.
Now when I click the visible button I need to do two things

1.Open Iframe.

2.Automatically make the 2nd Button(Hidden)to be clicked.

When the second button is clicked I need to display the message on top of the IFrame which I have mentioned as `function showStickySuccessToast()`

Now I am able to open IFrame but I'm unable to make the Hidden button clicked automatically.

This is what I'm having:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function(event){
            $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').change(function () {
                $('#various3').attr('href', $(this).val());
            });
    });
       function showStickySuccessToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showToast', {
            text: 'Finished Processing!',
            sticky: false,
            position: 'middle-center',
            type: 'success',
            closeText: '',
            close: function () {

            }
        });
    }
    }) 
    </script>
```

Here are my two buttons how I'm working with:

```
<a id="various3" href="#"><asp:Button ID="Button1" 
runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Button2_Click"/></a>

<asp:Button ID="Button2" 
runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="False" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
```

And in the button2_Click event:

```
    Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
       System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "showStickySuccessToast();", True)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use UpdatePanels?

Comment: I haven't tried yet with the update panels just I was trying with simple way to acheive this and further I'm planning to use the update panels and Is it good to use here in this application?May be I need most of your suggestions to make my application to work in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this inside the click event for your first (visible) button:

```
$("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function(event){
       $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').change(function () {
             $('#various3').attr('href', $(this).val()); 
       });
       $("#<%=Button2.ClientID%>").click();
});
```

Comment: First thanks for the reply and If I do this It gives me error as server tag is not well formed.

Comment: That is formed the same as your other click event (just with a different ID). Maybe rebuild? I'm not sure why that would cause an error.

Comment: @ Nate-Thanks I rectified my error and thanks for solving out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
           <script type="text/javascript">
               $('#Button1').click(function () {
                   if ($('#TextBox1').val() == '') {
                       alert("Error")
                       $('#TextBox1').focus();
                       return false;
                   }
               });
</script>
    </div>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```